# IIS 7.5 IP address works but fully qualified name does not

Tags: iis-7

Here are the steps (Windows Server 2008, R2, IIS 7.5)

- create new virtual folder under default web site
- create new application in that virtual folder
- add helloworld.htm page to that application
- access helloworld.htm with no issues using fully qualified name http://server_name/virtual_folder/application/helloworld.htm
- for the application, change Security->Authentication to require Windows Authentication and not allow anonymous authentication
- in order to access same page you need to use ip_address instead of server_name.

Please help!

Thanks PV

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue, changing the ApplicationPool identity to `NetworkService` solved it.

I found the solution [here](http://www.shaundanielz.com/post/MVC3-IIS-75-Windows-Authentication-Troubleshooting.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this could be a dns problem, can you try and create a host entry (c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts and put the mapping there FQDN -> IP

See if that works.

Comment: Not Authorized

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

HTTP Error 401. The requested resource requires user authentication.

Comment: First, thanks for the reply. After modifying host file, I still get HTTP Error 401 (see above). If you have any other suggestions please let me know.

Comment: @Change to allow anonymous access on IIS?